# looking for Best guidance for WCF best performance testing

Tags: performance, wcf

when some one developing wcf service which will be consumed and used by thousand of people then what are the key point we need to keep in the mind to design web service which will deliver best performance. so please give me all the best tips to design wcf service which can help service to give best performance. thanks

another question what are tools and technique is used in the industry to test the performance of wcf service before hosting in production server. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the design, make sure that service is (ok , cliches but still worth to mention)

- Easy to scale
- Stateless (Per-Call)
- Uses no locks
- Caches data

Well in general it should be "just" highly performant but it of course depends on your use-cases so it is more important that you know **how** your users will use the system :

- you wrote thousand of people but you should have exact numbers defined
- will the service will be used only on certain hours ? If so , maybe it's possible to compute / cache any data that will be heavily used before ?
- what is the required throughput /number of calls per sec / avg. number of users working ?
- what about peak volumes ? Is it used constantly or it's just users loading data at one time and then nothing ?
- where is it going to be hosted ? IIS or self-hosted ? Can you control it ? How is the security plugged int ? Is security a concern  ?
- who calls your service ? Is SOAP ok ? Can you use REST ?

So the point is that to get best performance you need to have clearly defined goals like "I want to handle 1000 calls per sec and each call uses around 2MB of data" :)

As for the tools a best one is something that resembles your end-users so for final testing it could be a bunch of selenium tests and for perf testing even a console application spamming your endpoints will work **but** a key factor here is separation so that your services are hosted on different server then test-client

Comment: thanks for the answer. Stateless (Per-Call) means there will no session enable and each request will be handle by new instance? what is the meaning of Uses no locks? how to Caches data in wcf? please help me to get the above all points clear. thanks